# Pulling data off RAID 5 drives without booting to an OS?

Tags: backup, raid

I have a Dell server that will not boot and I need to get data off the disks inside. The HDDs are 300GB each in RAID 5 and I have a couple large 2TB HDDs that I would like to pull the data to. What would be the best way to go about this?

Details:

- 10 300GB drives with data I need in RAID 5
- The server that will not boot is Dell 720xd
- 2 2TB drives to pull the data to
- I do not have a server with enough bays to completely transfer all 10 300GB drives to so I am thinking I will need to back up the 300GB drives in bunches

Is there a way to initiate a backup from the raid controller without having to boot into an OS so I can leave the 300GB drives where they are? Am I barking up the wrong tree?

Comment: "Is there a way to initiate a backup from the raid controller without having to boot into an OS"  No, you'll need an OS to access the file system.  Install a new OS on a different drive and then access the RAID, or pull the RAID card and drives, and hook them to a working computer.

Comment: Many dell servers have an internal USB for booting off a USB stick. A lightweight OS that can mount NTFS for reads would fit on such a stick and this would resolve your lack of drive bays.

Comment: Ah that's a good idea

Answer (score 1):

> Am I barking up the wrong tree?

I am starting with this since there is an obvious alternative solution. Just get the data from your backups of that Dell server. No need to boot it.

(Given that you did set up a RAID 5 array I assume that the data is important, and hence I know you have not only backups, but actually up to date and tested backups.)

Now that my preaching life lesson is out of the way, lets try to solve your problem. For that we need a bit more data. Without that I am just going to give broad answers based on likely combinations.

Lets start with what does "the server will not boot" mean?  Does the actual server fail to come up, or does it power up, pass POST and tries to load the OS?  Does the OS bootloader fail? Does the OS start and then fails? Are their failed disk lights on 2 or more of the RAID 5 array?

Briefly:

- If it is only the OS which fails to load then a liveCD (or live USB) will get you up and running. All you need is one with the drivers for the RAID controller and for the network or USB. Copying the data off is then trivial.
- If the entire server fails to boot then it gets more tricky. Best case if if you have a hardware RAID card and RAID layout stored on the disks. That would allow you to moveboth disks and RAID card to a different PC and either boot or go the LiveCD route.
- If you have a build in HW RAID (and based on page 26 of [this manual](http://topics-cdn.dell.com/pdf/poweredge-r720_Owner's%20Manual_en-us.pdf) there is one in the 720 series) then your best bet are similar servers or a cheap second hand 720 from ebay or similar.
   As to similar systems, Dell will be able to tell you which of their RAID cards are compatible. Call them, their poweredge/business support desk is quite good.

Comment: Just to add - be careful removing the raid card to a different machine - I've known some cards to 'reset' and completely forget the config they had once removed. Some store it on the disks, some don't... A good way is to take photos of each of the raid screens configuration options (If it's hardware raid and boots).

Comment: Aye. As far as I can make out most modern ones store it on the disk. And a 745 is not an ancient server. So it is *probably* fine. Having written that, I have an ` and RAID layout stored on the disks` in that bulletpoint.